# Can I set a custom "alt" attribute with woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail()?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Can I set a custom "alt" attribute with woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail()?

like so.. woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail("custom alt");

Answer (score 1):

You can't with `woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail()`, but this will give you the exact same result:

```
global $product;

$image_size = apply_filters( 'single_product_archive_thumbnail_size', 'woocommerce_thumbnail' );
$custom_alt = 'Put your custom alt text here.';

return $product ? $product->get_image( $image_size, [ 'alt' => $custom_alt ] ) : '';
```